# TICoreDataSync with dropbox SDK giving 'path not found' error

Tags: iphone, objective-c, dropbox, dropbox-api, ticoredatasync

I've followed the tutorial found [here](http://timisted.github.com/TICoreDataSync/ios-tutorial.html) to set up my app for dropbox sync. When i start the app, thus starting sync, i get this:

```
[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/dropbox/com.timisted.notebook - Path '/com.timisted.notebook' not found

[WARNING] DropboxSDK: error making request to /1/metadata/dropbox/com.timisted.notebook/Documents/Notebook - Path '/com.timisted.notebook/Documents/Notebook' not found
```

And a list of similar errors.

Any ideas what the cause of this is, and how I could fix it?

EDIT: I tried this with the example app provied with TICoreDataSync, using my credentials, and it accepted the credentials but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found you can typically ignore these messages.  TICoreDataSync will try and make the request and then if it fails, it will create the folder and continue.

Here are the changes I had to make to get iOSNotebook to run:

1. Dropbox wouldn't let me create an app called “iOSNotebook” as it was already taken (no surprises there :)). So I changed the name of the Xcode project and target to iOSNotebookCA along with the TICDSDropboxSDKBasedApplicationSyncManager's globalAppIdentifier to @"com.timisted.iOSNotebookCA"
2. Next I had to change Build Settings > Build Active Architectures Only = Yes
3. I changed the deployment target to 5.1 so I could avoid having all test devices running 6.0 (optional)
4. I also had to change the info.plist file's URL string to reflect the Dropbox key assigned to my iOSNotebookCA (db-blahblahblah).
5. And changed the DBSession root to kDBRootAppFolder

Answer (score 0):

We recently released version 1.0.2 of the framework along with updated documentation, example apps, and tutorials on the [project wiki](https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync/wiki). Check it out and if you run into any snags open an issue on the project's [Issues](https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync/issues) page